# Can Ajax be supported on Sharepoint 2007. Unknown Server tag 'asp:ScriptManager'

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-applications, sharepoint-2007, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use Ajax on sharepoint 2007. I am using a webapplication template for in visual studio 2008. Here i am building the .net solution and copying the aspx pages to my sharepoint webapplication and at the same time copying the dll from my local to the bin folder of sharepoint web application. I also copied the ajax toolkit to the same bin folder where i copied the project dll.

I am using a simple calendar extender control and binded it to a text box. I am able to get the out put when i run it on my local machine. But the problem exists when i am deploying the same code on sharepoint web application.

I have gone through lot of blogs and forums  all i saw is editing the web.config file of sharepoint web application and some suggest to install sharpeoint service pack 1.

Below is the error i am getting when i deploy my code on the sharepoint server.

"Unknown server tag 'asp:ScriptManager' "

Can anyone please help me to make AJAX work on the sharepoint server 2007.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to make these web.config changes in order to enable AJAX on SharePoint 2007

http://zieglers.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/webconfig-entries-for-enabling-ajax-for-sharepoint-2007/